# Exercise 3.F.35 Show that $(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}))'$ and $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ are isomorphic (Linear Algebra Done Right 3rd Edition by Sheldon Axler)

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, linear-transformations, dual-spaces

I am reading "Linear Algebra Done Right 3rd Edition" by Sheldon Axler.

> 1.22 **Example** $\mathbb{F}^\infty$ is defined to be the set of all sequences of elements of $\mathbb{F}$: $$\mathbb{F}^\infty=\{(x_1,x_2,\dots) : x_j\in\mathbb{F}\text{ for }j=1,2,\dots\}.$$

> 2.11 **Definition** ***polynomial***, $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{F})$
>
> - A function $p:\mathbb{F}\to\mathbb{F}$ is called a ***polynomial*** with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}$ if there exist $a_0,\dots,a_m\in\mathbb{F}$ such that $$p(z)=a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+\dots+a_mz^m$$ for all $z\in\mathbb{F}.$
> - $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{F})$ is the set of all polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}.$

> 3.94 **Definition** ***dual space***, $V'$
> The ***dual space*** of $V$, denoted $V'$, is the vector space of all linear functionals on $V$. In other words, $V'=\mathcal{L}(V,\mathbb{F})$.

> Exercise 3.F.35
> Show that $(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}))'$ and $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ are isomorphic.

I tried to solve this exercise, but I was not able to solve this exercise.

I know the following facts:

> $\varphi:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})\ni p\mapsto p^{(n)}(a)\in\mathbb{R}$ is a linear functional, where $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $p^{(n)}$ is the $n$th derivative of $p$.
> $\varphi:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})\ni p\mapsto \int_{a}^{b} p(x) dx\in\mathbb{R}$ is a linear functional, where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What is $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Hint: what do you know in general about linear transformations and bases?

Comment: I gather that by $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ you mean the space of all real valued sequences, right?

Comment: @OliverDíaz Thank you very much for your comments. I edited my question.

Comment: HintL $\{1, x,x^2,\ldots\}$ form a basis for $V:=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$. If $\Lambda\in V'$ then $\Lambda$ is uniquely characterized by its values on the basis. Thus, you can associate to $\Lambda$ the sequence $a_n=\Lambda(x^n)$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$. Conversely, given a sequence $a_n$ show that $\Lambda_a: x^n\mapsto a_n$ is a liner functional. Racall that on $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{Z}_+}$, sum is pointwise.

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić Thank you very much for your hint.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Thank you very much for your answer.